# How do I write this LINQ query in fluent syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 'GetTransactions' method that returns an object of type:

```
IList<ApplicationTransaction>
```

Where this is an ApplicationTransaction:

```
public partial class ApplicationTransaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

How do I convert this LINQ query:

```
return (from t in GetTransactions().OfType<ApplicationTransaction>()
        where t.Event == transactionType.ToString()
        select t).FirstOrDefault();
```

Into fluent syntax?

This doesn't work - what am I not understanding?

```
return GetTransactions().OfType<ApplicationTransaction>().Where(t.Event == transactionType.ToString().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can use LINQPad (or Reflector) to see its fluent flavor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parameter to a lambda in your where statement:

```
return GetTransactions()
    .OfType<ApplicationTransaction>()
    .Where(t => t.Event == transactionType.ToString())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

(Notice `t =>` part where defines a new expression scope instead of directly trying to access a variable "t")

You don't need a separate select if you're selecting the whole entity.

I also suggest using the multiline layout I used in the answer to understand the query better and catch potential problems like the missing parenthesis issue @nvoigt mentioned.

Comment: He's also missing a closing `)` you correctly set. Maybe good to mention.

Comment: There .Where(...) is redundant, you can ommit it and write `FirstOrDefault(t => t.Event == transactionType.ToString());`